# latexmk: jobname option and clean up incompatibility?

Tags: latexmk, makefile

I'm using [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) in a Makefile to compile my document.
Since I want my output filename to be different from the input filename, I use latexmk's option `jobname`.

The problem is: it seems to be incompatible with `latexmk -c` to clean temporary files.

Here's the specific entry in my Makefile:

```
these.pdf: header.tex $(OBJS)
    latexmk                 \
        -pdf                \
        -pdflatex="$(TEX)"  \
        -jobname="these"    \
        -use-make $<
```

Input files are `header.tex` containing the latex instruction header and other latex content files. The output files are `these.{aux,bbl,bcf,...}`.
Then `latexmk -c` does not remove temporary files: .{aux,bbl,bcf,...} files.

Answer (score 5):

You need also to specify the `-jobname` option when you use `latexmk -c`, i.e.,

```
latexmk -c -jobname=these header.tex
```

Comment: I don't think adding the `.tex` file is necessary.